# LinearLayout in LinearLayout with 3 elements - one alligned to the left, one centered and one alligned to the right

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

Good evening.

I'm fiddling with this for over an hour now and I don't get it to work.
I want to create a layout that should look like this:

[image]

I'd like to have a TextView alligned to the left, a ProgressBar centered and another TextView alligned to the right. I don't want to use static widths, because the layout should be used for different devices.

Unfortunately my layout looks like this at the moment:
[image]

I didn't find any solution via google, so any help is really appreciated.
This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtProgress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0 %" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.36" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25sp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="100 %" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do well to try a `RelativeLayout` like so:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/yourTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20pt"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/yourTitle">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0 %" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.36" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25sp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="100 %" />
        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Which produces something like this:

[image: Image of layout from emulator]

Answer (score 1):

I've just add `weight` to the text views and set their `width` 0dp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtProgress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0 %" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25sp"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="100 %" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried you code and it work correctly for me. But you can try chage `android:layout_width` to 0dip in ProgressBar.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```